# How many $x$ for which $ \tan x=x-x^3$?

Tags: trigonometry

What are the number of solutions of

$$
\tan x=x-x^3
$$ 
where $x$ belongs to $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Notice that $x=0$ is a solution. Notice further that the function $x \mapsto \tan{x} -(x-x^3)$ is monotonically increasing on $(-1,1)$ (why?). Conclude that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are an infinite number of solutions over the natural domain of tan.
Thus we must focus on real solutions over $(-1,1)$. Here is a generalised approach to such problems.

One such and obvious solution is $x = 0$, but any others must be deduced using the bisection method. The intermediate value theorem states that if $f$ is a continuous function over $[a,b]$, there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f(c) = z$ for some $z$ in $(f(a),f(b))$ (if $f(a) < f(b)$, or $(f(b),f(a))$ if $f(a) > f(b)$. Thus we can say there is a solution, $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$ for some $c$ in $(a,b)$ where $f(a) < 0$ and $f(b) > 0$ or vice versa.

For instance let us consider if there is (at least one) a solution in the interval $[0.01,1] $.
Let $f(x) = \tan (x) - x - x^3$ and compute 
$f(0.01)$ and $f(1)$ say.

If there is a sign difference between these, by IVT, there is a least one real solution in that interval. You can split the interval further to see if there are more roots in that interval (or more accurately, define the bounds for roots). Also helpful tip: for every root in the interval $(0,1)$ there must be a root in $(-1,0)$ given $f$ is odd.

Of course noting the graph of $f$ say in Wolfram Alpha (after you do your calculations) can help to verify your solutions.

N.B. Non existent sign change does not necessarily imply there are NO zeros over the chosen interval. This just means we cannot guarantee there will be a zero (or in fact no zeros) over the interval unless we sufficiently prove $f(x) < 0$ or $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$. In some cases, real roots only become obvious when we take an appropriate subset of the interval.